# websolr not indexing? ("401" Status: Authorization Required)

Tags: drupal, solr, websolr

I´ve just installed Websolr and tested the connection, and works.
But nothing gets indexed.
I´ve got a drupal 7 site, and when I click the configuration files tab, I get this error:

```
"401" Status: Authorization Required: Authorization Required<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</HEAD>
<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorised.</H1></BODY>
</HTML>
```

My logs don´t show anything.

Answer (score 0):

At [websolr](https://websolr.com/home), we run indexes in a shared cluster environment. One of our design principle is to whitelist access to specific index actions that we know to be safe and secure. This approach limits access to most administrative actions within Solr, due to performance, security and/or privacy concerns.

In this case, the Drupal apachesolr module makes a request to `/admin/stats.jsp` in order to fetch some usage statistics for the index's usage. Unfortunately the HTTP 401 response from our end is treated as a fairly severe error and reported as such.

[image: Drupal apachesolr 401 authorization required error]

We're still working on options for working around this either within the module itself or at our end on our service. For a workaround, and more up to date summary, you can keep an eye on this article on our Support Knowledge Base:

- [Websolr Support - Drupal apachesolr module: "401 Authorization Required"](http://help.websolr.com/kb/common-problems/drupal-apachesolr-module-401-authorization-required)